# Is there another German interpretation of "See no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil"?

Tags: expression

My German was far better as a child then it is now.  I am currently attempting to re-learn it.  During this review, an anecdote that I've repeated frequently has come under scrutiny.

While in Switzerland, I was quizzing my sister in front of a small figure of the three wise monkeys.  I asked her to translate "see no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil".  Looking now the expression in German seems to be **"nichts (Böses) sehen, nichts (Böses) hören, nichts (Böses) sagen"**.

Immediately after that exchange, we were approached by a strange man who explained that "here" they say **"Sehe alles. Höre alles. Spracht nichts."**  (The grammar might be off but that is what I remember.)  He then proceeded to explain what that meant to him as to how we should behave though out lives. I coincidentally met that memorably man several times over several years in several countries which is why this story is usually worth remembering.

At the time (and until today) I assumed what he told me was accurate but cannot find the expression online.  **Is this an actual German (or Swiss or Austrian) expression** or his own creative speech on how we should grow? It may be Schweizerdeutsch as the exchange occurred in Basel.

Comment: Well...the third verb should be "spreche nichts", if it should be in line with the other two.

Comment: @Veredomon Yeah, this logical grammar difference from what I remember is what caused to search for it.  I explictly remember the "t" sound so he might have said "Sprecht nichts" but his explanation works better with the more logical grammar.

Comment: See also [de:WP, Drei Affen, Bedeutungswandel in der westlichen Welt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drei_Affen#Bedeutungswandel_in_der_westlichen_Welt) (change of meaning in the western world) with link to en:WP, too.

Comment: Well, if _Sehe alles. Höre alles. Spracht nichts._ should contain imperatives, then it should be _Sieh alles. Hör(e) alles. Sprich nichts._

Comment: Most dialects would use _sagen_ instead of _sprechen_ here, so _Alles|Nichts sehen, alles|nichts hören, nichts sagen!_ or _Sehe X, höre X, sage nichts!_ using weak imperative or _Sieh X, hör X, sag nichts!_ with strong imperative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's his own expression. I never heard that version and I also didn't find anything on the internet. The grammatical correct version would be: "Alles sehen. Alles hören. Nichts sagen."